# Filter on value in a list of values in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have a table and I can't change the schema...

```
 id    values
 3     4, 6, 7
 4     9, 3, 9
 5     1, 2, 8
```

How do I filter rows on a specific indexed value in a list of values? 
For example, I want to pass rows whose second value in the list of values is less than the number 6 and so rows with id 4, 5 pass, but id 3 is filtered out.

Comment: By changing the database structure. Why do you think you need to store a list in a single column?

Comment: @CL.Let's assume I can't change the schema...